# Calling graph API using Powershell - Passing JSON as Body

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to call `https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenID)/oauth2/v2.0/token` using powershell by passing below parameters:

```
$requestBody = @{client_id=$CliID;client_secret=$CliSec;grant_type="password";username=$Username;password=$Password;scope=$Scope} | ConvertTo-Json
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenID)/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Body $body
```

However, I unable to pass body as JSON and call the same API. I want it to be in JSON formatted to be used in Power Automate to call HTTP endpoint.
I used below as JSON and request:

```
$JSON = '{
    "grant_type":  "password",
    "password":  "pwd",
    "client_id":  "clieid-12345-32234",
    "client_secret":  "jewhfjkjlskw;fdslk;",
    "username":  "user@example.com",
    "scope":  "Directory.AccessAsUser.All"
}'
Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenID)/oauth2/v2.0/token" -ContentType "application/json" -Body $JSON
```

I am always getting error as below while passing it as JSON:

**`Invoke-RestMethod : "error":"invalid_request","error_description":"AADSTS900144: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'grant_type'.`**

Can you please help?

Comment: update the string to here string... e.g: `@'` at the start and `'@` at the end instead of `'{` `}'`

Comment: Passing body as 
`@'
    "grant_type":  "password",
    "password":  "pwd",
    "client_id":  "clieid-12345-32234",
    "client_secret":  "jewhfjkjlskw;fdslk;",
    "username":  "user@example.com",
    "scope":  "Directory.AccessAsUser.All"
'@`
is returning error as Malformed JSON.

Comment: as far as I know the token endpoint only accepts payloads which are x-www-form-urlencoded. You can't just send JSON if the token endpoint doesn't expect this.

Comment: Any idea how to pass hashtable while calling API in power automate? HTTP action is only accepting JSON payload. :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that this will work for you.

```
$data = @{        
    grant_type = "client_credentials";
    password = "pwd";
    client_id = "clieid-12345-32234";
    client_secret = "jewhfjkjlskw;fdslk;";
    username = "user@example.com";
    scope = "Directory.AccessAsUser.All";
};
$json = $data | ConvertTo-Json
$url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($TenID)/oauth2/v2.0/token"
$contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"  

Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -ContentType $contentType -Body $json
```

Comment: Posting json to the Microsoft token endpoint is not supported as far as I know. According to the oauth2 and openid specifications you'll have to use application/x-www-form-urlencoded when requesting a token